# OpenSceneGraph: Don't update the z-buffer when drawing semi-transparent objects

Tags: graphics, rendering, transparency, openscenegraph

## Question

Is it possible to tell OpenSceneGraph to use the Z-buffer but not update it when drawing semi-transparent objects?

## Motivation

When drawing semitransparent objects, the order in which they are drawn is important, as surfaces that should be visible might be occluded if they are drawn in the wrong order. In some cases, OpenSceneGraph's own intuition about the order in which the objects should be drawn fails—semitransparent surfaces become occluded by other semitransparent surfaces, and "popping" (if that word can be used in this way) may occur, when OSG thinks the order of the object centers' distance to the camera has changed and decides to change the render order. It therefore becomes necessary to manually control the render order of semitransparent objects by manually specifying the render bin for each object using the `setRenderBinDetails` method on the state set.

However, this might still not always work either, as it in the general case, is impossible to choose a render order for the objects (even if the individual triangles in the scene were ordered) such that all fragments are drawn correctly (see e.g. the [painter's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Painter%27s_algorithm#/media/File:Painters_problem.svg)), and one might still get occlusion. An alternative is to use [depth peeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth_peeling) or some other [order-independent transparency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order-independent_transparency) method but, frankly, I don't know how difiicult this is to implement in OpenSceneGraph or how much it would slow the application down.

In my case, as a trade-off between aestetics and algorithmic complexity and speed, I would ideally always want to draw a fragment of a semi-transparent surface, even though another fragment of another semi-transparent surface that (in that pixel) is closer to the camera has already been drawn. This would prevent both popping and occlusion of semi-transparent surfaces by other semi-transparent surfaces, and would effectivelly be achieved if—for every semi-transparent object that was rendered—the Z-buffer was used to test visibility but wasn't updated when the fragment was drawn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're totally on the right track.

Yes, it's possible to leave Z-test enabled  but turn off Z-writes with `setWriteMask()` during drawing:

```
// Disable Z-writes
osg::ref_ptr<osg::Depth> depth = new osg::Depth;
depth->setWriteMask(false);
myNode->getOrCreateStateSet()->setAttributeAndModes(depth, osg::StateAttribute::ON)

// Enable Z-test (needs to be done after Z-writes are disabled, since the latter
// also seems to disable the Z-test)
myNode->getOrCreateStateSet()->setMode(GL_DEPTH_TEST, osg::StateAttribute::ON);
```

https://www.mail-archive.com/osg-users@openscenegraph.net/msg01119.html

http://public.vrac.iastate.edu/vancegroup/docs/OpenSceneGraphReferenceDocs-2.8/a00206.html#a2cef930c042c5d8cda32803e5e832dae

You may wish to check out the osgTransparencyTool nodekit we wrote for a CAD client a few years ago: https://github.com/XenonofArcticus/OSG-Transparency-Tool

It includes several transparency methods that you can test with your scenes and examine the source implementation of, including an Order Independent Transparency Depth Peeling implementation and a Delayed Blend method inspired by Open Inventor. Delayed Blend is a high performance single pass unsorted approximation that probably checks all the boxes you want if absolute transparency accuracy is not the most important criteria.

Here's a paper discussing the various approaches in excruciating detail, if you haven't read it:
http://lips.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/files/bathesis_cbluemel_digital_0.pdf

Comment: Hm, according to the paper, it seems like 'delayed blend' is precisely what I described. By `depth->setWriteMask( false )`, I guess you mean the [`setWriteMask`](http://public.vrac.iastate.edu/vancegroup/docs/OpenSceneGraphReferenceDocs-2.8/a00206.html#a2cef930c042c5d8cda32803e5e832dae) method in the `osg::Depth` class, but how do I get a `osg::Depth` object?

Comment: @HelloGoodbye You can create a new osg::Depth object and attach it to the stateset as myNode->getOrCreateStateSet()->setAttributeAndModes(depth, osg::StateAttribute::ON);